# How to get output in sublime in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu version 16.04 and sublime, but I'm unable to install MAMP.
So now, how can I get the output webpage of my HTML code at sublime page?

Please suggest some software to get the output webpage.